# How to efficiently implement function iteration in R

Tags: r

In R, what is the most efficient way of implementing

```
y[1] = x[1]
for (i in 2:length(x)) {
    y[i] = f (y[i-1], x[i])
}
```

where x is my input and f is a given function?
Ideally I would have liked to be able to say

```
y[1] = x[1]
y[2:N] = sapply (2:N, function (i) {f(y[i-1], x[i])}) # WRONG of course!
```

But this is of course wrong. Is there a built-in looping function that will do this for me?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example and specify what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Reduce` will reduce the number of keystrokes needed to do this sort of operation:

```
Reduce(f, x, accumulate=TRUE)
```

For instance, let's consider a simple case where you are just adding the elements (of course `cumsum(x)` would be more efficient in this case):

```
x <- c(1, 2, 4, 5)
Reduce("+", x, accumulate=TRUE)
# [1]  1  3  7 12
```